# Magento 2.3.X Zend\Http\Header\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Invalid header value detected

Tags: magento2.3.x

I have Magento 2.3.3 and we create a clone instance 
Everything is working fine on admin but the frontend stop loading on clone instnace

Here is the error

```
`Zend\Http\Header\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Invalid header value detected in /chroot/home/a539234/website.com/html/sites/mysite/vendor/zendframework/zend-http/src/Header/GenericHeader.php:53
Stack trace:
#0 /chroot/home/a539234/website.com/html/sites/mysite/vendor/zendframework/zend-http/src/Header/GenericHeader.php(33): Zend\Http\Header\GenericHeader::splitHeaderLine('Location: http:...')
#1 /chroot/home/a539234/website.com/html/sites/mysite/vendor/zendframework/zend-http/src/Headers.php(471): Zend\Http\Header\GenericHeader::fromString('Location: http:...')
#2 /chroot/home/a539234/website.com/html/sites/mysite/vendor/zendframework/zend-http/src/Headers.php(479): Zend\Http\Headers->lazyLoadHeader(0, true)
#3 /chroot/home/a539234/website.com/html/sites/mysite/vendor/zendframework/zend-http/src/Headers.php(372): Zend\Http\Headers->lazyLoadHeader(0)
#4 /chroot/home/a539234/website.com/html/sites/mysite/vendor/zendframework/zend-http/src/PhpEnvironment/Response.php(91): Zend\Http\Headers->current()
#5 /chroot/home/a539234/website.com/html/sites/mysite/vendor/zendframework/zend-http/src/PhpEnvironment/Response.php(126): Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response->sendHeaders()
#6 /chroot/home/a539234/website.com/html/sites/mysite/vendor/magento/framework/HTTP/PhpEnvironment/Response.php(39): Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response->send()
#7 /chroot/home/a539234/website.com/html/sites/mysite/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\Response->sendResponse()
#8 /chroot/home/a539234/website.com/html/sites/mysite/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->___callParent('sendResponse', Array)
#9 /chroot/home/a539234/website.com/html/sites/mysite/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#10 /chroot/home/a539234/website.com/html/sites/mysite/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Response/Http/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->___callPlugins('sendResponse', Array, Array)
#11 /chroot/home/a539234/website.com/html/sites/mysite/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(206): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->sendResponse()
#12 /chroot/home/a539234/website.com/html/sites/mysite/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(177): Magento\Framework\App\Http->handleDeveloperMode(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(Zend\Http\Header\Exception\InvalidArgumentException))
#13 /chroot/home/a539234/website.com/html/sites/mysite/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\Http->catchException(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(Zend\Http\Header\Exception\InvalidArgumentException))
#14 /chroot/home/a539234/website.com/html/sites/mysite/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->___callParent('catchException', Array)
#15 /chroot/home/a539234/website.com/html/sites/mysite/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(Zend\Http\Header\Exception\InvalidArgumentException))
#16 /chroot/home/a539234/website.com/html/sites/mysite/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->___callPlugins('catchException', Array, Array)
#17 /chroot/home/a539234/website.com/html/sites/mysite/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(267): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->catchException(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(Zend\Http\Header\Exception\InvalidArgumentException))
#18 /chroot/home/a539234/website.com/html/sites/mysite/index.php(42): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#19 {main}`
```

I also have rename the vendor and did composer update to make sure the vendor is not missing any files but still having the same issue
Any idea what is going wron here ?

Comment: did you try composer update?

Comment: Yes, I did mention that in my question . I did compose update and run commands

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing this isuee, did u find a solution?